# Nginx - Adding a trailing slash to urls on HTTPS

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, regex, regular-expressions

I am using the below regex to add a trailing slash to any url that doesn't have a railing slash or ends ends with ..

```
rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
```

This works fine for **http**, but when I use **https** it doesn't. I can't work out why? Can you?

Comment: Enable rewrite_log in Nginx and see why it doesn't work!

Comment: @Pothi Already, it just says it doesn't match. Which is odd, because it does.

Comment: Odd indeed. Please try `if ($uri !~* "/$") { return 301 $scheme://domainname.tld$uri/; }` instead of the rewrites.